# Redux Toolkit caseReducers skip prepare callback in reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I have a reducer for adding comment as follow

```
addComment: {
  reducer: (state,action)=>{
    const { newId, comment } = action.payload
    console.log(newId)
    // functions that create an new comment entry with the newID and update state
  },
  prepare: (input) =>{
    return {
      payload: {
        ...input,
        newId: nanoid(),
      }
  }
}
```

If I call dispatch within my app as follow, the console.log shows the id generated by nanoid(). So far so good.

```
dispatch(addComment({comment: comment}))
```

However if I call the reducer within another reducer using the caseReducers, console.log returns undefined

```
commentSlice.caseReducers.addComment(state,{
  payload: {
    comment : comment
  }
})
```

How do I get the prepare callback to run when using caseReducers.

Answer (score 2):

[Based on the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createslice) it looks like if you are to invoke using the caseReducer way, you need to include the "type":

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => state + action.payload,
  },
})
// now available:
slice.actions.increment(2)
// also available:
slice.caseReducers.increment(0, { type: 'increment', payload: 5 })
```

Comment: Adding type does not work. caseReducer still skips prepare function (undefined new Id) while dispatching reducer directly from the app did run the prepare function (newId generated)